From which games are the characters shown in the 2024 Steam Turn-Based RPG Fest banner?
Steam is currently running the 2024 Steam Turn-Based RPG Fest. The webpage banner displays several characters that appear to be from turn-based RPG(s): a red ogre/giant and three goblins on the left, an armored knight with a huge sword, a pink-haired person wielding knives/daggers, and a wizard with a pointy hat and a staff whose tip is glowing green.

Are these characters from specific turn-based RPG(s)? If so, which games are they from?

Interesting that what one would assume are the "good guys" are on the right - in most turn-based games, the good guys are on the left, while the bad guys are on the right.

Especially since the "good guys" appear to be "your team" - the green arrow is who you're currently controlling, and the pointer finger is who you're going to attack (or whatever the chosen action is). At least, that's what it looks like when the animation plays on Steam.

I believe these are original creations, as is often the case with the (larger-scale) sales and fests organized by Steam themselves (e.g. Steam Summer Sale 2022, Steam Visual Novel Fest).
The official trailer for the fest showcases several games, but none of them seem to match the characters in the banner. Featuring only a tiny selection of games would also imply favouritism, which I'm sure Steam would like to prevent.

Something that could also support this is that all of the characters appear to be drawn in the same art style, which would be unlikely if they were sourced from multiple games.

@Daemons Not entirely: at times these events do feature characters from other games, drawn, perhaps by a single artist, in a similar style (like this one).

I kind of miss when Steam's promotional banners and images used to feature references from actual games rather than generic artwork. Those were always more interesting.
